# Modify image on every download

Tags: image, amazon-s3, base64

so my current task is to receive image from my host (currently s3), but the catch is that nothing should be persisted about this image, what this means is that i can not persist its url, for example since s3 always includes the same key name in the url even if it is presigned, i can not use that data directly, the solution for this would be to create a image server which would download the image from s3 and send it back to client but url for this image would be always dynamic and random (with jwt), now problem is that, base64 that i have just received is persistent, it is not changed, what can i tradeoff is that i can randomly modify characters inside the base64 string, maybe 2,3 characters that would mess up pixel or two but as long as its not noticeable thats okay with me, but this technique seems bit slow, because of bandwidth size, is there any way that i can use to make image non persistent and random every time client receives it?

Comment: Just modifying the contents of a modern image format will likely lead to corrupting, not just changing some pixels.  You need to decode the image, change some pixels, re-encode the image and send it along.  This has nothing to do with S3, though.

Comment: Please read & apply [ask]. Remember, [we're here to help](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2002/10/11/were-here-to-help).